# How to turn off the axis in tikz plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Anyone knows how to let the axis disappear from my plot.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[colorbar]
    \addplot3
        [surf,faceted color=blue,
        samples=15,
        domain=0:1,y domain=-1:1]
        {x^2 - y^2};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Use `hide axis`